# Remove rows present in one .csv from another .csv (windows, powershell, notepad++)

Tags: powershell, csv, notepad++

I have notepad++, powershell, and excel 2007. I have two .csv files named 
*database.csv* and *import.csv* . Import.csv contains new entries that I want to put
into my database online. Database.csv contains the current records in that database.
Both files contain a simple comma-newline delimited list of unique values.

However, the database may already contain some entries in the new file. And, the new
file contains entries that are not in the database. And, the database file contains
entries that are still retained for recording purposes, but are not in the input file.

Simply combining them results in duplicates of any record that has an ongoing existence.
It also results in single copies of records only present in the database and records only
present in the input file.

What I want is a file that only contains records that are only present in the input file.
Any advice?

Comment: do you any columns that make the row unique in the file? id? first+lastname?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your csv files have the columns a, b, & c:

```
$db = Import-Csv database.csv
$import = Import-Csv import.csv
$new = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $db -DifferenceObject $import -Property a,b,c -PassThru | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | Select a,b,c
```

Just replace a, b, and c with the names of the columns you want to compare

Comment: this doesn't work properly with csv-objects(at least for me). also, this will return "new" rows from `$db` too, which he doesn't want

Comment: @Graimer: you're right, I hadn't tested it, that was from memory. I've just updated my answer with a tested solution.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell:

```
Get-Content <database file> -TotalCount 1 |
 Set-Content C:\somedir\ToUpload.csv


$import = @{}

Get-Content <import file> |
 select -Skip 1
 foreach {
          $import[$_] = $true
         }

Get-Content <Database file> |
select -Skip 1 |
 foreach {
           if ($import[$_])
             {
              $import[$_].remove()
             }
         }

 $import.Keys |
  Add-Content C:\Somedir\ToUpload.csv
```

Alternatively, reading both files into memory:

```
Get-Content <database file> -TotalCount 1 |
 Set-Content C:\somedir\ToUpload.csv

$import = Get-Content <import file>
 select -Skip 1

$database = Get-Content <database file>
 select -Skip 1

$import |
 where {$database -notcontains $_} |
 Add-Content C:\somedir\ToUpload.csv
```

The solutions using import / export csv will work but impose additional memory and process overhead compared to dealing with the files as text data.  The difference may be trivial or substantial, depending on the size of the files and the number of columns there are in the csv files.  IMHO.

Comment: if you're looking for performance on large files, you should avoid `get-content` all together =)

Comment: I think that depends on the application and how you use Get-Content. Compare [IO.File]::ReadAllLines to Get-Content -ReadCount 0.

Comment: ofc, but for larger files get-content is slow, period.

Comment: By default it's slow because it's reading content and building an array.  If you don't need the array, use ReadCount 0, or if you want to stream and have V3, us the -Raw switch.

Comment: `[IO.File]::ReadAllLines(path)` builds an array too, but only string-array and works alot faster. it depends on what you need(e.g. support to add noteproperties) but if you just need an array of strings, `IO.File` or a `StreamReader` is usually faster. At least that's what I've experienced. :)

Comment: The pont about handling this problem using string comparisons vs object comparison stands. I'll address any objections you have to that, but I don't think this needs get turned into a long discussion about the most efficient way to read those strings in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`Compare-Object` struggles sometimes with customobject imported from csv if you don't have any specific properties to match.

If you want performance(for large csv files), you could try this:

```
$i = @{}
[IO.File]::ReadAllLines("C:\input.csv") | % { $i[$_] = $true }

$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader "C:\db.csv"

#Skip header. This way the output file(new.csv) will get input.csv's header
$reader.ReadLine() | Out-Null

while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    #Remove row if it exists in db.csv
    if ($i.ContainsKey($line)) {
        $i.Remove($line)
    }
}
$reader.Close()

$i.Keys | Add-Content c:\new.csv
```